# Get Month value from week value in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get the Month value from Week No.

Suppose if a week is shared by two months, then I need to get two months

Ex
 
When input Week No 30, result should be month 7
If Week No 31 - it is a shared week, it should return month 7(2 days) & 8(3 days)

2 week days in July and 3 week days in august

I tried datepart method which is not useful for me

```
dyWk = DatePart( "w", #07/31/2018# ) // Here date as input
```

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/04/29/excel-weeknum-function-convert-week-number-date/

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little ambiguous but does this give you what you need?

```
week = 30
year_to_use = 2018
month_at_start_of_week = Month(DateAdd("ww", week - 1, DateSerial(year_to_use, 1, 1)))
month_at_end_of_week = Month(DateAdd("ww", week, DateSerial(year_to_use, 1, 1) - 1))
```

When week = 30, you get:

```
month_at_start_of_week = 7 
month_at_end_of_week = 7
```

When week = 31, you get:

```
month_at_start_of_week = 7 
month_at_end_of_week = 8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How could get number of days in both months From the example For July its 2 days & for Aug its 3 days

Comment: I see you've selected an answer, apologies, I thought you wanted a VBA solution not a Formula.

Comment: Please check why I am getting two different months for week number 13; Its not a shared week

Comment: According to this, week 13 starts on the 26th March and ends on the 1st April?

Comment: Is there any flag to set to consider the week start on sunday and ends on  Saturday

Could you also help to get count of days in both months

Answer (score 1):

From that [link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/04/29/excel-weeknum-function-convert-week-number-date/) you can get start of week, in `C2`, with

```
=DATE(A2, 1, -2) - WEEKDAY(DATE(A2, 1, 3)) + B2 * 7
```

and end of week,in `D2`, with

```
=DATE(A2, 1, -2) - WEEKDAY(DATE(A2, 1, 3)) + B2 * 7  +6
```

And then get the month of each returned date, in `C3` and `D3` respectively

```
=MONTH(C2)  and =MONTH(D2)
```

and do a distinct count, in `E3`, with

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(C3:D3,C3:D3))
```

---

Data

[image: Data]

---

Note

This is based on ISO week numbers.

For days in each month

In `C4` put `=EOMONTH(C2,0)-C2+1` and in `D4` put `IF(C3<>D3,D2-EOMONTH(D2,-1),)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. How could get number of days in both months
From the example For July its 2 days & for Aug its 3 days

Comment: In C4 put =EOMONTH(C2,0)-C2+1   and in D4 put   IF(C3<>D3,D2-EOMONTH(D2,-1),)

Comment: Week 13 is not a shared week, But I am getting two different months

Comment: Then you have made a mistake. ISOWEEK 13 for 2018 starts on 26/3 and ends on 01/04 which is 2 months.

Comment: You can verify as =ISOWEEKNUM(C2) and =ISOWEEKNUM(D2) both return 13 for 26/3 and 01/04.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172698/discussion-between-qharr-and-manimuthupandi).